# Where is the only Aerostar 800 ever built?

Tags: aviation-history

The [Ted Smith Aerostar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_Aerostar) has a very interesting history. Wikipedia has a list of all the models that were built. There's a note there about an Aerostar 800, only one of which was ever built. Does anyone know where that 800 is today?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://aerostar-owners.com/ChristyModels.php) page the airframe was donated to Embry-Riddle Aeronautical University:

> The Superstar airframe was later used as the prototype Aerostar 800. The prototype 800 was the Superstar airframe with two more seats (due to a 32” extension of the cabin) and featured two 400-hp. Lycoming engines. The 800 was under development when Ted unexpectedly passed on in 1976. Piper continued development of the airplane as a replacement for their P Navajo but never certified it and eventually donated the airframe to **Emery Riddle [sic] Aeronautical University**.

This is the only reference I can find to the ultimate location of the Aerostar 800.

Comment: @Pondlife, you just beat me to that edit :-)

Comment: Even though I was searching around their site I never once picked up the misnaming in the linked article. Thanks

Comment: @DeltaLima :-) Amusingly, someone has even created a Facebook page for "Emery Riddle Aeronautical University" in Kentucky, which is a real ERAU campus. Hopefully the person isn't a student, or that would be really embarrassing...

Comment: @Pondlife `This Page is automatically generated based on what Facebook users are interested in....` Facebook users are obviously interested in mistyped university campuses :)